# How different is compiling source code in Debian GNU/Hurd from Debian GNU/Linux?

Tags: debian, compiling, c, hurd

I was trying to compile [`libnetfilter_conntrack`](https://github.com/threatstack/libnetfilter_conntrack) source from github as it was requested by [`iptables`](https://github.com/shadowsocks/iptables) while compiling ***iptables*** and as any of these were not available in the HURD software repo and ended up in an [error](https://pastebin.com/f1LY6Nt6) while configuring `libnetfilter_conntrack`

```
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
configure: error: Linux only, dude!
```

and my kernel is,

```
$ uname -a
GNU debian 0.9 GNU-Mach 1.8+git20190109-486/Hurd-0.9 i686-AT386 GNU
```

and my ultimate goal was to compile [iproute2](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2).

Comment: The matter here is not the difference between compiling on Hurd and Linux: Is that you are trying to compile a Linux-only firewall and lib on another OS.

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is a *new* program on the GNU/Hurd whose command-line interface is similar to that of the programs `iptables` and `iproute2`. This *may* be possible as the networks (IPv4 and IPv6) that are being configured are similar. In that case look at the source of the equivalent programs on the GNU/Hurd and write a new command-line interface for them.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In general, it’s not very different; there are lists of known pitfalls [on the Hurd’s site](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd/porting/guidelines.html) and [on the Debian wiki](https://www.debian.org/ports/hurd/hurd-devel-debian#porting_issues). Many projects build fine, or after a few fixes (the most common issue being the absence of `PATH_MAX`).

However in your case you’ll find it difficult to get anywhere: `netfilter` and `iptables` are specific to the Linux kernel, so you won’t be able to use them on the Hurd. You’ll probably have noticed that [the `iptables` package isn’t available on `hurd-i386`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/iptables) — there’s usually a good reason for that... [`iproute2`](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2) is also Linux-specific.

On the Hurd you’d use `eth-filter` instead, see the networking section of [the Debian GNU/Hurd configuration guide](https://www.debian.org/ports/hurd/hurd-install) for details.

Comment: @PavelSayekat Using a firewall not specifically written for Linux?

Comment: @PavelSayekat You can always port the libraries/programs to hurd. Happy coding for the next few years!

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta won’t work, because the libraries and programs are just the userspace half of the implementation; they talk to specific Linux kernel modules, so this won’t ever be possible.

Comment: @mirabilos unless someone adds “kernel” support on the Hurd too ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt the Hurd principle would rather make that into a translator which then talks to the network translator. No kernel involved, it basically only does message passing. (Oh, and I’d rather port pf from OpenBSD than whatever Linux uses these days… ☺)

Comment: @mirabilos I know, which is why I put the term “kernel” in quotes. And yes, porting `iptables` would be rather pointless, it’s already in the past...